# Can't access object's function after calling `operator new` explicitly

Tags: c++, placement-new

I'm working on a project which I have to implement `new operator` and `delete operator`, and manage my memory by my own MemoryManager - which has Lists of available memory.

In order to allocate my lists and nodes (which should not need to be managed), I should invoke `operator new` explicitly after calling `malloc`.

When I'm trying to call a function - `setNext()`, it throw an exception:Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
Creating HashTable of LinkedLists:

```
MyHashTable::MyHashTable(size_t memorySize, void* startingPtr)
        :size(getLowerLog(memorySize) + 1), lists((LinkedList**)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList*) * size)), startingPtr(startingPtr) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        auto memSize = (size_t) pow(2, i);
        void * l = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
        lists[i] = new (l) LinkedList(memSize);
        // Placement new
    }
    dividingMemory(memorySize, startingPtr);
}
```

The `dividingMemory` function does:

```
void MyHashTable::dividingMemory(size_t memorySize, void* startingPtr) {
    while (memorySize > 0) {
        size_t memPow = getLowerLog(memorySize);
        auto max = (size_t) pow(2, memPow);
        lists[max]->add(ptr);              // here is the call to LinkedList::add()
        startingPtr = ((char*) startingPtr) + max;
        memorySize -= max;
    }
}
```

LinkedList::add() :

```
void LinkedList::add(void * ptr) {
    void* p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node * newNode = new (p) Node(ptr);
    // Placement new
    newNode->setNext(head);
    std::cout << "haha" << std::endl;
    head = newNode;
    size++;
}
```

Whole Node class:
Node.h:

```
#ifndef EX3_NODE_H
#define EX3_NODE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Node {
private:
    void* ptr;
    Node* next;
public:
    explicit Node(void*);
    inline Node* getNext() const {
        return next;
    }
    inline void setNext(Node* next) {
        this->next = next;
    }
    ~Node() = default;
};
#endif //EX3_NODE_H
```

Node.cpp:

```
Node::Node(void * ptr):ptr(ptr) { }
```

I've tried to call another function (toString) and it secceded.


What am I doing wrong?

I tried @Ben Voigt's answer but it didn't solve it.

Comment: That use of `new` is usually called "placement new".

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes i know.. that's why it comes after a malloc..

Comment: @RustyX I've added, thanks

Comment: @Yinon I made that comment because the question mentions `operator new` a lot, but the examples do not use it or mention it.

Comment: What does the rest `Node` look like?

Comment: @Yinon • works on my machine, after I added some surrounding code.  The phrase "throwing an exception" is usually in the context of a C++ thrown exception.  EXC_BAD_ACCESS means you are accessing bad memory, and I'd expect it to crash your application rather than throw an exception (but maybe your environment packages it up as a C++ exception).  You'll need to use a debugger.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux hi yes, this part should not invoke it at all. These classes should be allocated without calling operator new.

Comment: That's not a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: @PhilBrubaker added, thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your problem (I believe), but you'll want to initialize `next` in the `Node` constructor.

Comment: Also a question: In `MyHashTable::dividingMemory`(), the line: `lists[key]->add(ptr);`: where are `key` and `ptr` coming from?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Placement `new` *does* call `operator new`, the version that takes a pointer argument instead of a size.  This version by default just returns the input argument instead of allocating a new block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic mistake, I've tried to access an undefined memory location.

```
auto max = (size_t) pow(2, memPow);
lists[max]->add(ptr);
```

Should be:

```
auto max = (size_t) pow(2, memPow);
lists[(log(max) / log(2)]->add(ptr);
```

Comment: Why would you do that calculation?  `log(max) / log(2)` is just `memPow`.

Answer (score 3):

You are throwing away the return value of placement `new`, which is the only formally correct way of getting a pointer to the newly constructed object.  You then call member functions on the raw-storage pointer you passed into placement new.  Don't do that.

This is the correct way to use malloc together with placement new:

```
void* rawBlock = malloc(sizeof(Node));
Node* newNode = new (rawBlock) Node(ptr);

// later
newNode->~Node();
free(rawBlock);
```

Comment: Assuming a `Node* foo = (some pointer)` and `Node* bar = new (foo) Node(ptr)`, in what cases will `foo` and `bar` not be aliases? Or must you just use `bar` to satisfy some legalese that says that you can't use `foo` after it's been used as the argument to a placement new?

Comment: +1 everybody on this entire thread.  It has been very educational, and I am glad I do not need to dabble in C++ memory management and object construction/destruction at this detailed and fine-control level.

Comment: @BenVoigt It would be great to know ***why*** there is a bug and not only ***where*** is the bug.

Comment: @zneak: For arrays, they definitely are not guaranteed to be equal.  For single objects, both pointers will have the same address in memory, but they still get treated differently by the compilers strict-aliasing analysis (see the strict aliasing rule).  Also yes, there are restrictions on what you can do with a pointer after overwriting what it points to with a brand new object.

Comment: @StavAlfi: I did explain, the code is confusing a pointer to raw storage and a pointer to an object.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't solved it. still getting an exception

Comment: @BenVoigt, I don't understand what you mean with "for arrays". I don't see how `new (foo) int[100]` is any different in terms of the address that is returned, and I'm unable to make it vary in [this example](https://godbolt.org/g/PTTmTk). As for strict aliasing, `void*` and `char*` are exempt; in addition to that, the original code casted the result of malloc to a `Node*`, and I don't see how two objects of the same type can have strict aliasing issues.

Comment: @zneak: Try with a data type that has a destructor.  Strict aliasing does not exempt `void*` and `char*` completely -- it is asymmetric.